How do I get Time Machine to Warn when backups haven't happened?
A family member routinely unplugs their backup drive (because no one has enough USB ports) and then forgets to plug it back in for weeks or months. How do I make Time Machine notify and warn them if a backup hasn't taken place for several days?

It isn't doing that already?  My MBP certainly does, if it is away from its normal backup target (my Synology) for more than a few days.  I didn't do anything to turn that on.

Specifically Time Machine starts sending notifications after 10 days

Apple does show notifications by default and place the icon in the Menu Bar.  Have you tried those and found they get ignored or were not explained why all the family pictures will be lost if this doesn’t happen regularly?
I find a weekly backup with a monthly check on paper works for people to have a habit to really check if a backup is good. Also, have you tried a restore in the last 18 months? That’s really the only check that is meaningful in the end.
Setting these up in the reminder app or a shared calendar also works well for a more prominent alert.

I used to have frequent errors in Time Machine backups (they stopped when I upgraded to either Sonoma or Sequoia), which would cause it to stop backing up. I ran an application called TM Error Logger that would monitor TM's log file and send email if it reported a problem.
